# Слово-агрессор. Как обороняться?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, жаргон

Вопрос о слове "кавардак" напомнил о паре "бардак-бардачок". Эти, т.н. слова, поддерживая друг друга (где-то видел даже: бардачок - уменьш. от бардак), заставляют думать, что не нашлось в целом языке другого подходящего названия ящичку. От вульгарных к просторечным поднимаясь, они вскоре сместят литературное и в приличные зачислены будут.

Comment: @shampar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Вы полагаете, что правильный ответ существует и он у меня в рукаве?

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Имеется в виду "чем заменить слово бардачок"?

Answer (score 1):

Другое название "ящичку" нашлось. Он называется отделением для перчаток. В силу разных обстоятельств по прямому назначению в России использовался крайне редко, а вот всяких мелочей у большинства водителей хватает. Куда ж их, как не туда? Так что "бардачок", действительно уменьшительное от бардака (имхо), рожденное народом. А народ перевоспитывать... Вот кофе уже среднего рода))

Comment: Innak, кофе не "уже", оно уже давно среднего рода в качестве разговорного. ))

Comment: Народ, так и быть, трогать не будем, - пусть его неприбранная комната бардаком зовётся. Но за ближний-то круг можно и побороться.
Хотя понятно, что от "бардака рождённое народом" и так, само-собой не долго протянет.

Comment: Отделением для перчаток он был еще в те далекие времена, когда шофер был открыт всем ветрам и носил специальные очки чтобы ветер не дул в глаза, ну и перчатки чтобы защитить руки (а не для красоты и элегантности). Потребность в такой форме одежды отпала уже давно, поэтому там действительно хранят всякие мелочи.